# Secure Boot - how does Linux revoke/blacklist vulnerable boot loaders/boot managers/kernel/modules signed with shim's built-in key?

Tags: linux-kernel, security, kernel-modules, boot-loader, secure-boot

### Background

Shim can have a certificate built into it during compilation (see "Shim keys" paragraph [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html)). The corresponding private key can then be used to sign the boot loader/manager and kernel. This approach abstracts Microsoft's UEFI signing away from those components - only shim needs to be Microsoft-signed, the rest are distribution-signed, enabling them to be updated and released quickly while maintaining the chain of trust.

### Blacklisting

If vulnerabilities are found in the boot loader/manager or the kernel, then they must be patched and a new version signed and released. But we can't use the same signing key anymore can we? If we do, then shim would still be able to load the older, vulnerable versions. If the vulnerabilities could be exploited to execute arbitrary code, then attackers can turn them into bootkits and circumvent Secure Boot. This means that a new shim has to be built with a new certificate, and the old shim's hash must be blacklisted in Secure Boot's dbx.

I'm not very familiar with how kernel modules are signed and verified across distros, though I would hazard a guess that there would be cases where they are signed and verified against a certificate built into the kernel. If vulnerabilities enabling arbitrary code execution are found in any module, then it would have to be patched and resigned with a new kernel key, which means the kernel would have to be signed with a new shim key, which means the old shim must again be blacklisted in dbx.

### Issue

This doesn't seem like a viable approach in the long run. Vulnerabilities in the boot loader, kernel, and kernel modules are continuously being found and fixed, which means we need to continuously generate new key pairs, rebuild shim with the new certificate, and blacklist the old shim. In addition any distro that allows users to install and/or run them while Secure Boot is enabled, and without prompting users to install certificates/hashes into the Secure Boot db, is probably using a shim with the distro's certificate built-in. This means we have to blacklist shims from all affected distros whenever an arbitrary code execution vulnerability is found in any of the aforementioned components. This won't be an issue for advanced users who are able to replace Microsoft's keys with their own, but it seems like regular users would have to continuously update their dbx in order to stay secure. Is this really the case here? Or is the number of distros using built-in keys too small for this to be an issue?